How to condense connected nested generics
I have the following situation:
I have some objects with a common superclass like this that already use generics:
class Location extends TemporalEntity<LocationId>
class Character extends TemporalEntity<CharacterId>
abstract class TemporalEntity<T extends ReadableUuid>

Now, I want to use these in another abstract class that requires both the TemporalEntity and its associated ReadableUuid. Currently, I am doing that like this:
class LocationViewTemplate extends TemporallyLimitedTemplate<Location, LocationId>
class CharacterViewTemplate extends TemporallyLimitedTemplate<Character, CharacterId>
abstract class TemporallyLimitedTemplate<T extends TemporalEntity<I>, I extends ReadableUuid>

While this works, I am somewhat bothered by the fact that I need to pass on the ID types again, since they are already defined in the Location and Character respectively. It feels like there should be some way that I can just write it like this:
class LocationViewTemplate extends TemporallyLimitedTemplate<Location>
class CharacterViewTemplate extends TemporallyLimitedTemplate<Character>

To achieve that, I have tried writing the TemporallyLimitedTemplate like this:
abstract class TemporallyLimitedTemplate<T extends TemporalEntity<I extends ReadableUuid>>

However, when I do it, I get this compiler error:
The name 'I' isn't a type, so it can't be used as a type argument. (Documentation)

Basically, what I want to tell the compiler to do is: "I am going to give you one type as your generic that contains another type as its own generic, and I want you to use your generic type as T and the generic type contained within as I".
Is that possible in dart? And If yes, how do I write it correctly?
